# skuDetailsList returning null

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I am trying to implement in-app purchases using the latest **Google Play Billing** Library (2.0.1)

• I've Added product Ids to the skuList and in the Google Play Console after publishing apk in Internal App Testing

• But when I launch billingFlow I get the following

```
2019-07-01 13:17:02.436 1225-1225/com.mypackage.myapp D/InAppBilling: Other code5
2019-07-01 13:17:02.436 1225-1225/com.mypackage.myapp D/InAppBilling: Invalid SKU input params. SKU can't be null
```

Here's my code:

```
List skuList = new ArrayList<>();

        skuList.add("product_1");
        skuList.add("product_2");
        skuList.add("product_3");
        skuList.add("product_"4);

 SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                                && skuDetailsList != null) {

                            for (Object skuDetailsObject : skuDetailsList) {
                                skuDetails = (SkuDetails) skuDetailsObject;
                                String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
                                String price = skuDetails.getPrice();
                                if ("product_1".equals(sku)) {

                                    textA.setText(price);
                                } else if ("product_2".equals(sku)) {
                                    textB.setText(price);
                                } else if ("product_3".equals(sku)) {
                                    textC.setText(price);
                                } else if ("product_4".equals(sku)) {
                                    textD.setText(price);
                                }
                             } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Sku is null");
                             }
                        Log.d(TAG, "i got response");
                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(billingResult.getResponseCode()));
                        Log.d(TAG, billingResult.getDebugMessage());
                    }
                });

    mBuyButton = findViewById(R.id.pay);
    mBuyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

     BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                            .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                            .build();
     mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(PayActivity.this, flowParams);
        }
    });
```

and here's the logcat

```
2019-07-01 13:17:04.173 1225-1225/com.mypackage.myapp D/InAppBilling: Sku is null
2019-07-01 13:17:04.173 1225-1225/com.mypackage.myapp D/InAppBilling: i got response
2019-07-01 13:17:04.173 1225-1225/com.mypackage.myapp D/InAppBilling: -1 //billing result response code 
2019-07-01 13:17:04.173 1225-1225/com.mypackage.myapp D/InAppBilling: Service connection is disconnected. //debug message
```

I have also tried with reserved test product ids ***android.test.purchase*** but same error

I have also uploaded app on Play Console (internal testing) but it didn't work from there too

Any help is appreciated...

**EDIT:**
After lots of experiments I found that Billing Service is being disconnected
but the reason is not as below
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.BillingResponse#service_disconnected (-1)

```
mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(PayActivity.this).setListener(this).enablePendingPurchases().build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {


            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Connection finished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                //TODO implement your own retry policy
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                mBillingClient.startConnection(this);
            }
        });
```

and after getting response onBillingSetupFinished is being called

Comment: did you add test users credentials

Comment: you mean testers in Play Console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue solved it by moving my app to alpha testing

Comment: How long did it start working after you moved to alpha.

Comment: I published the app in internal testing and installed from there

Comment: Wait, you need to install the App for you to get the SkuDetails. Can't it work when you run the App straight from Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Retry connecting

```
@Override
public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {

  if(!billingResult.getResponseCode==BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
       mBillingClient.startConnection(this);
  }

  Log.d(TAG, "Connection finished");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i forgot to add newly added subscription on play console in following code, then i added it and issue was gone.

```
public void querySKUDetails(SkuDetailsResponseListener listener) {
    if (!isBillingClientReady) {
        return;
    }
    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<> ();

    // you need to add your new subscription sku here
    skuList.add(BillingConstants.SKU_POPULAR_MONTHLY);
    skuList.add(BillingConstants.SKU_PREMIUM_YEARLY);

    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(SkuType.SUBS);
    mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
            listener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your skuList like this and then add products -

```
List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<> ();
   skuList.add("product_1");
    skuList.add("product_2");
    skuList.add("product_3");
    skuList.add("product_4");
```

Comment: yeah but that's not the issue

Comment: kindly it check now

Comment: Sure, checking.

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />`

Comment: Did you add the product ids in Play Console?